# During uninstallation the dll does not remove from system32 folder

Tags: installscript

```
I have a 64-bit InstallScript set up.
```

The only problem is figuring out what I uninstall set up the dll does not delete from system32 folder.

I can't find anything in the documentation that explains how to accomplish this task. I am using InstallShield 2011, thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

The SYSTEM32 folder is supposed to contain only permanent components that are never uninstalled. Not sure about InstallShield's implementation, but the regular MSI testsuite flags an error if you define a File that installs there and do not mark it *Permanent*.

Thus, I'd change to a different location.